# Rails gem pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have the following hash:

```
MAPPING = {
   create: [:admin],
   update: [:admin],
   delete: [:admin],
   index: [:all]
}
```

And I need to create pundit method dynamically in the policy class.
I need to search the mapping hash all items that have admin role and create policy methods:

```
def create?
   true
end

def update?
   true
end
```

This way I don't have to repeat the code all the time.
How can I do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code below defines a method for each key whose value contains `:admin`. The name of the method is the key, cast to a string, with a question mark appended. Each defined method returns `true`.

```
MAPPING.each do |action, roles|
  define_method("#{action}?") do
    true
  end if roles.include?(:admin)
end
```

Comment: what is the best way to store these mapping hashs ? a concern ?

Comment: That really depends on the wider context here. If the constant is specific to this class, it could simply live inside it.

Comment: the problem is that I don't have access to roles on class scope. So I can't run define_method to create the methods dinamically.

Comment: How *do* you have access to the hash?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using:

```
    class CarPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
      attr_reader :user, :record

      def initialize(user, record)
        @user = user
        @record = record
      end

      PERMISSION_KEY_MAPPING = {
        index: [:admin]
      }

      PERMISSION_KEY_MAPPING.each do |action, roles|
        define_method("#{action}?") do
          true
        end if user.roles.include?(:admin)
      end
    end
```

The line:

```
end if users.roles.include?(:admin)
```

Doesn't work because I don't have access to user.roles.